# Issue creating a default Docker compose network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ipv4

I created a network, added the containers to the network and tried docker-compose up with the correct ip's that are on the network.json file but I can't put the containers up

network.yml

```
{
    "Name": "cogsi-docker-network",
    "Id": "bcc0491f8fd3b5cf5ccbc1f4927c03fabcda850f529f4269155f63ff9e4806c4",
    "Created": "2023-04-17T21:06:22.8480161Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "4f129e5129c2eefd356e4c6571bb819d5c837b3fcb7a5a551c3d3fd7e69196ef": {
            "Name": "compose-nagios-1",
            "EndpointID": "395d2d8b75aa8ff679c6a5226ff71bf36c5436c91dcc5c080f78e26600e2c523",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "a19a9e45cc56256c31bb241e8fdbda03c0d8c304f56472fd06615616019df554": {
            "Name": "compose-todd-1",
            "EndpointID": "a07c0dd8e88bc227235c1b70e604c6f2d712f197d1b422bb79dd9687f2416548",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
```

docket-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nagios:
    build: nagios
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.19.0.2
  todd:
    build: todd
    ports:
      - "10500:10500"
      - "3006:3006"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/host
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.19.0.3
networks:
  cogsi-docker-network:
    external:
      name: cogsi-docker-network
# networks:
#   default:
#     ipam:
#       driver: default
#       config:
#         - subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
```

The error displayed is the following: Error response from daemon: Invalid address 172.19.0.2: It does not belong to any of this network's subnet

Comment: The `docker network inspect` output you show is for a network named `docker-network`, but in your `docker-compose.yaml` you're referring to a network named `cogsci-docker-network`. It looks like you may have misnamed your network when you created it.

Comment: I changed the name by mistake on the post, thanks for letting me know

Comment: You are connecting your containers to the `default` network, but the address you're setting is for the `cogsi-docker-network` network. Change the network name in your `networks:` setting for each container.

Comment: I have fixed it but know it runs locally. It said that I was definning manually the ip's and when I remove the ```network: ``` part of each service it runs but locally still

Answer (score 0):

Delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the Compose file.  Completely ignore the container-private IP addresses.  Don't bother running `docker network inspect` or other low-level diagnostic commands.

Internally Docker happens to assign each container a unique unroutable IP address.  It's useful to know this happens, since this means you can multiple containers that all listen on the same port, but you never need to know this.  The container-private IP addresses are unreachable from outside Docker (except in one very specific host-OS/Docker configuration), and between containers, the Compose service names like `nagios` and `todd` are usable as host names.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nagios:
    build: nagios
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    # Note: no `networks:` and no manual IP assignment
    #
    # Sample cross-service URL setup:
    # environment:
    #   TODD_HEALTH_URL: http://todd:3006/health
  todd:
    build: todd
    ports:
      - "10500:10500"
      - "3006:3006"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/host
    # Note: no `networks:` and no manual IP assignment
# Note: no top-level `networks:`
```

Comment: This answer is useful to simplify a basic Docker-Compose setup, but people will need networks for something a bit more complex like wanting to share a database container between microservices that each have their own Compose files.

Comment: You shouldn't share databases between microservices.  Each service's Compose file can declare its own database, and since each Compose file has a separate `default` network they won't conflict.

Comment: If you don't share the database container between microservices you'll incur the memory overhead of running a separate engine for each. If you share the container, you can still have different databases for each service.